Best Practice for Tracking Customers in SFMC Journey: Update Contact Activity vs. Data Views?
I'm working on a customer journey in Salesforce Marketing Cloud (SFMC) and need to track customer interactions effectively. I'm considering two options:

Update Contact Activity - Using this to directly update contact data within the journey.
Data Views - Leveraging Data Views for tracking and reporting on customer activities.
I want to ensure that I choose the best practice for tracking that is both efficient and scalable.

Which approach is considered the best practice in SFMC for tracking customers in journeys? Are there any specific considerations or recommendations for choosing between Update Contact Activity and Data Views? Any insights or experiences would be greatly appreciated

I think the best solution depends on what you wish to achieve. Can you describe what kind of customer interactions you are interested in tracking?

I would like to get information about entry date and exit date (I can obtain them through update a tracking DE) and the reason for exit (e.g. meet exit criteria) which I can't get through update DE.

The best way would be to set an automation to fetch Journey History data and then analyse it per your requirement.
Check those links for more information:

Get Journey history by filtering the Definition ID via API
Download Journey History REST API Endpoint


Thanks. What if I want to obtain data about entry/exit and exit reason for all the journeys (I have 20+). Is the non-documented API efficient enough to handle it?

Generally, you can retrieve the info about Journey's settings, configuration and activities via GET /interaction/v1/interactions endpoint. Then you can also parse all the Journey History data to see what contacts entered/exited the journey and etc.

Thanks, but this API will only return information about the journey and the activities it contains, not details about when a contact entered/exited, what the exit reason was, etc.
Moreover, I’m concerned that even if I managed to obtain such data, it wouldn’t allow me to create an automated process that saves this information into a Data Extension to build a master DE containing the entire consumer path through all journeys – when they were in each one and what they received. SSJS has a 30-minute limit, so considering I have few k of interactions daily, it wouldn’t be able to process.

Journey History API endpoint will give what is needed but yes, you are right, it is a very tedious process to request, parse and save whole Journey History data. Of course, it always depends on a number of journeys, contacts and activities but generally speaking, that is not a good approach to capture everything. Try to think about applying some filters or selectively saving only needed data.

Thanks! Have you ever implemented such solutions before? Assuming I have around 100 000 entries per day into the journey (I mean Start Activity), would SSJs be able to process this within 30 minutes (the max time out)?

the /interaction/v1/interactions/journeyhistory/search post api call has a limit of 10.000 items, so you would need to limit the result based on a variable, e.g., limit based on time or journey name (i.e., definitionNames)
Handling this amount of data should not be a problem. It depends on the rest of the logic you are setting up, but as long as you are running it from automation studio and not a cloud page it should be fine.
Check this out: https://gortonington.com/journey-history-for-last-30-days-via-api/
